# traceroute shows just * * * in linux ( in a virtual machine ), although displays all IPs in windows correctly

Tags: traceroute

I did tracert to google in windows PowerShell and IP addresses of all stations are displayed properly.

However, if I do the same in Linux in a virtual machine to the same server, I see only * * * .

```
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  5.955 ms  5.568 ms  5.228 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Why this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packets that Windows `tracert` and Linux `traceroute` use by default are different. Windows `tracert` sends ICMP packets and Linux `traceroute` sends UDP packets. The UDP ports are blocked at each hop in your example but ICMP is allowed, so that explains the discrepancy you're seeing.

From [Wikipedia: traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute):

> On Unix-like operating systems, traceroute sends, by default, a
>   sequence of User Datagram Protocol (UDP) packets, with destination
>   port numbers ranging from 33434 to 33534; the implementations of
>   traceroute shipped with Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, DragonFly
>   BSD, and macOS include an option to use ICMP Echo Request packets
>   (-I), or any arbitrary protocol (-P) such as UDP, TCP using TCP SYN
>   packets, or ICMP.
>
> On Windows, tracert sends ICMP Echo Request packets, rather than the
>   UDP packets traceroute sends by default.

You can have `traceroute` use ICMP packets in Linux by adding the `-I` option.

From [man traceroute](https://ss64.com/bash/traceroute.html):

> **traceroute**
>
> Print the route packets take to network host.
>
> **Syntax**
>         `traceroute [options] host [packetsize]`
>
> Options:
>
> ```
>  -I    Use ICMP ECHO for probes
> ```

Comment: is there a way to force traceroute in linux to also use ICMP? Maybe there is an option ?

Comment: Yes, use `traceroute -I `

Comment: I guess it is a limitation when using NAT in a VirtualBox. `traceroute -I` did not show the result either. `traceroute` only worked properly in a bridged mode for me.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Either disable Windows Firewall entirely, or allow ICMP Time Exceeded packets through WF.

I have a more detailed and thorough article on [my blog](https://ibug.io/p/40).

#### Problem

[This is the answer](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/traceroute-from-Ubuntu-just-shows-first-and-last-hops-on/m-p/1677267/highlight/true#M19955):

> If your Windows Firewall in turned on on your host, you will see this behavior - only the first and last device answers. If it's turned off, it works (at least for me).

The detailed reason is, `traceroute` works by sending ICMP Echo Requests with increasing TTL starting from 1, so when they "die of time", the intermediate routers send back **ICMP Time Exceeded** packets, which is **unexpected by Windows Firewall**.

#### Solution

The obvious solution is to turn off Windows Firewall entirely, but that's probably not safe for some users.

The solution **without turning off Windows Firewall** is to explicitly allow ICMP Time Exceeded (ICMPv4 Type 11 / ICMPv6 Type 3) to come in. This can be done as follows:

- Open Windows Firewall: **Start** → **Windows Administrative Tools** → **Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security** (yeah the name is verbose)
- Select **Inbound Rules** on the left
- Select **New Rule...** on the right

  [image]
- Follow the prompt. Select the following options in order:

  - Rule Type: **Custom**
  - Program: **All programs** (just click **Next**)
  - Protocol and Ports:

    - Protocol type: **ICMPv4**
    - **(Optional)** Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) settings: Click **Customize** → Select **Specific ICMP types** and tick **Time Exceeded**
  - Scope: **Any IP address** for both (just click **Next**)
  - Action: **Allow** (just click **Next**)
  - Profile: Select all (just click **Next**)
  - Name: **Core Networking - Time Exceeded (ICMPv4-In)** (apparently just any name you prefer)
- Click **Finish** and you should immediately see intermediate hops if you're using [`mtr` (My Traceroute)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)).
- **(Optional)** Repeat the above steps but select **ICMPv6** for *Protocol type* if you want to enable IPv6 traceroute.