# Traceroute output only stars, while tracert works

Tags: networking

I am testing `traceroute` command on my virtualbox ubuntu and windows subsystem ubuntu 18.0. None of them works. They show only stars. But when I test windows command `tracert` on the same computer, it works well. Can anyone help me? Thanks. Below is the Ubuntu traceroute output

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.377 ms  0.375 ms  0.363 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
```

============

Solved. add -I option to use ICMP. see [traceroute shows just * * * in linux ( in a virtual machine ), although displays all IPs in windows correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/1412029/traceroute-shows-just-in-linux-in-a-virtual-machine-although-displays)

Answer (score 6):

The default for Linux traceroute is to send UDP packets; the default for Windows is to send ICMP packets.

Some routers may/will block ICMP packets - but both varieties of traceroute can be configured to send ICMP/UDP/TCP packets.
It is suggested that you specify port 443 for UDP/TCP usage and you will likely need root access for TCP packets.

e.g. `sudo traceroute -T 8.8.8.8 -p 443`

lft  , the Layer Four Traceroute, performs a TCP traceroute, like traceroute -T , but attempts to provide compatibility with the original such implementation, also called "lft". It gives a nicer response:-

```
sudo lft 8.8.8.8

Tracing .....**********
TTL LFT trace to dns.google (8.8.8.8):80/tcp
 1  router (192.168.1.1) 0.6ms
**  [neglected] no reply packets received from TTLs 2 through 3
 4  128.hiper04.sheff.dial.plus.net.uk (195.166.143.128) 5.7ms
 5  core1-BE1.colindale.ukcore.bt.net (195.99.125.132) 5.5ms
 6  194.72.16.204 6.0ms
 7  109.159.253.195 6.1ms
**  [80/tcp no reply from target]  Try advanced options (use -VV to see packets).
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your command. I tried ```sudo traceroute -T 8.8.8.8 -p 443``` on Ubuntu, it outputs ```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.601 ms  0.291 ms  0.266 ms
 2  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  13.641 ms  19.794 ms  21.774 ms
``` if I use ```sudo traceroute 8.8.8.8 -p 443```, it just outputs star as before. On the same computer, if I test ```tracert``` on windows command, the output is normal. It seems we need do some setting on Ubuntu before running ```traceroute```? or is there any other reason?

Comment: Most of the time a plain `traceroute` domain-name works normally.
Indeed I tried a `traceroute 8.8.8.8` from a Debian VM running on a LMDE PC and it worked for me.
Perhaps you have a firewall or ISP "issue"? ??

Comment: Then why ```sudo traceroute -T 8.8.8.8 -p 443``` output ```dns.google.com``` etc., not just ***, and also ```tracert``` output correctly?

Comment: Because port 443 is the standard https port, I assume that google would not try to block TCP traffic on this port.